# Load image from the URL and overlay the image in map view?

Tags: android, overlay

I have a listview which consists of two textviews and an imageview. In the top of the layout (above listview), I have a button to show all the lists in map with the corresponding imageview and a textview. How can i overlay an imageview in the mapview..?

Note : I don't have any images in res - drawable. I have only image url.

I can able to pin the corresponding location..! but i don't know how to add overlay for that particular baloon(pin) with a imageview.

Besides, I have to draw a transparent circle for 2kms from the current lat and long in the mapview. Is that possible to draw a circle in the mapview..?

Help me to achieve the above.

The following is the code i used to show the map pin :

```
    Double lat1 = (Double.parseDouble(latitude)) * 1E6;
    Double lng1 = (Double.parseDouble(longitude)) * 1E6;

    com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint point = new com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint(
            lat1.intValue(), lng1.intValue());
    controller.animateTo(point);
    controller.setZoom(10);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
    balloon1 = new MyItemizedOverlay_Initial(drawable, mapView);
```

Comment: in short you want to display an image into ur mapview so that u can see where the house is ?

Comment: @user1469168 Yes.. But, Have to draw circle like [this] (http://m.blog.hu/po/pontehu/image/android_images/sample.png) and i should place a image in the dialog while clicking map pin

Answer (score 0):

You should extend com.google.android.maps.Overlay to add an image to a mapView. Then override draw method. Thus you can fetch URI adding a bitmap and drawing it within the canvas. Put code below in draw method.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://your.url.com/your-file.jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, point.x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, point.y - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, null);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```